# Flutter don't return value

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to make a Fetch Data on Flutter but my app gives the error:

```
The getter 'length' was called on null. Receiver: null Tried calling: length.
```

If I insert a log in `result.statusCode`, my value return in console.

I tried to consult other projects and documentation, but nothing works. I need the data to be applied to a label or even a text and return, but this is my main problem.

My code:

````
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';

class UserList extends StatelessWidget{

  final String apiUrl = "myAPI";

  Future<List<dynamic>> fetchUsers() async {

    var result = await http.get(apiUrl,
    headers: {HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader: "Bearer TOKEN"}); 


    if(result.statusCode == 200){
      return json.decode(result.body)['results'];
    } else{
      throw Exception('Não foi possível funcionar');
    }

  } 

  bool _sucess(dynamic sucess){
    return sucess['sucess'];
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('User List 1'),
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: FutureBuilder<List<dynamic>>(
          future: fetchUsers(),
          // ignore: missing_return
          builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
            if(snapshot.hasData){
              print(_sucess(snapshot.data[0]));
              return ListView.builder(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
                  itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index){
                    return
                      Card(
                        child: Column(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            ListTile(
                              leading: CircleAvatar(
                                radius: 30,
                                backgroundImage: NetworkImage(snapshot.data[index]['picture']['large'])),
                              title: Text(_sucess(snapshot.data[index]).toString()),
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
                      );
                  });
            } 
            else {
              print(_sucess(snapshot.data[3]));
              return ListView.builder(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
                  itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index){
                    return
                      Card(
                        child: Column(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            ListTile(
                              leading: CircleAvatar(
                                radius: 30,
                                backgroundImage: NetworkImage(snapshot.data[index]['picture']['large'])),
                              title: Text(_sucess(snapshot.data[index]).toString()),
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
                      );
                  });
            }
          },

        ),
      ),
    );
  }

} ```

My JSON: 

{
"success": true,
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 15014,
            "itens": [
                {
                    "data": "2020-06-23T14:38:03.000Z",
                    "pac": 6816608,
                }
            ],
            "podeImprimir": true
        }
    ]
} ```
````

Comment: Can you paste the json that you get from `apiUrl`? It seems that `results` is null

Comment: {"success": true,
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 15014,
            "itens": [
                {
                    "data": "2020-06-23T14:38:03.000Z",
                    "pac": 6816608,
                }
            ],
            "podeImprimir": true
        }
    ]
}

Comment: You don't have `results` in there. What do you expect when executing `json.decode(result.body)['results']`?

Comment: I was thinking that you could return the value in print `(_sucess (snapshot.data [0]));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `if (snapshot.hasData)` returns false, you are still calling `.length` on `snapshot.data`, which is why you're receiving an error.

```
...
else { // This code is executing because (snapshot.hasData) has returned false
     print(_sucess(snapshot.data[3]));
     return ListView.builder(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
          itemCount: snapshot.data.length, // This is causing the error, snapshot.data is null
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index){
...
```

Set your `itemCount` some other way, like with a constant- `itemCount: 1`, or with a variable that is not null.

Comment: Thanks! I change this and change the return too.